# What is the difference between DIMM modules labelled as PC3L 12800S vs 12800U?

Tags: memory, ddr3, sdram, sodimm, dram

What is the difference between DIMM modules labelled as *PC3L 12800S* and *PC3L 12800U*, respectively? I guess they are both low-voltage PC3 modules but AFAIK PC3L modules run at 1.35V (instead of 1.5V) while PC3U modules run at 1.25V.

Are these both PC3L modules or is the latter a PC3U module?

The 12800S module was a SODIMM module (laptop) while the 12800U module was a DIMM module (desktop) is the letter following 12800 referring to this? None of my other DIMM modules (DIMM or SODIMM) of earlier generation have suffixes after the number.

Answer (score 1):

PC3L 12800S is a SO-DIMM(small outline DIMM) module which is used in compact devices such as laptops and notebooks. And 12800U is a UDIMM (Unbuffered DIMM) module typically used in servers and desktop computers.
I don't think there's any official naming conventions for letters after the speed in megabyte(12800).

Additional Readings:

- [What is UDIMM](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/glossary/udimm/?orgRef=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)
- [DDR,DDR2...](https://hardwaresecrets.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ddr-ddr2-and-ddr3-memories/)
- [about naming conventions](https://avi.st/ddr-ram-identification-and-naming-conventions/)
- [Memory timings](https://hardwaresecrets.com/understanding-ram-timings/)

Comment: Hi Nandha  are you able to provide a reference for this?

Comment: I've added a few website where I read about how RAM naming is done. These are not references per se, but reliable sources. UDIMM is mentioned in [JEDEC ](https://www.jedec.org/system/files/docs/4_20_12R14.pdf)  Module 4.20.12 Page 10. (Registration Required)